# ASP.Net MVC Routing/Using Dynamic Actions

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing

Ok so I am trying to build a controller that has the following action methods

```
public ActionResult ExecuteStep_1a
public ActionResult ExecuteStep_1b
public ActionResult ExecuteStep_2
```

Etc...

Is there a way to define a route that uses a get parameter concatenated to the action name?  So for instance the URL would be /step/ExecuteStep_1a.  I tried defining a route with URL equal to:

```
{controller}/{action}_{number}
```

with no success.  I tried a few other permutations again with no results.  If someone could point me in the right direction I'd appreciate it.  Oh I set action equal to ExecuteResult_ with the default if that adds to my explanation any.

Answer (score 1):

You can use root Action and them use reflection like that:

```
{controller}/{action}/{step}

public ActionResult ExecuteStep(string step){
   try {
      Type thisType = this.GetType();
      MethodInfo theMethod = thisType.GetMethod("ExecuteStep_" + step);
      return theMethod.Invoke(this, null);
   }
   catch {}
}
```

But there is some speed limitation, if you using Reflection.

Comment: I was trying to avoid having a "root" action. Ultimately, I ended up going with a unique routing record for each action I wanted to map. So I have a url defined as {controller}/1a, {controller}/1b, etc. The defaults put in the controller and corresponding action name, in this case Step and ExecuteStep_1a, ExecuteStep_1b, etc. I decided even if I could use reflection to pull this off, the benefits aren't worth the effort and additional processing.

Comment: @Shawn Yeah, this will be smarter choice, if you don't have too many actions (steps), the reflection is there only one of the way how to achieve your needs.